# Socket IO Client receiving object DIFFERENT from what Server sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am sending an object from my server side to my client side, and the object that the client gets is totally different than the object I send. Here's what I mean:

---

## Code

**Server side code:**

```
//Basic setup for the example
var res={};
res.models=[];
res.models[0]={};

//The OLD (wrong) value
res.models[0]['id']="b4fd12f1-61ca-4445-b916-62617f1c0a78";

//The NEW (correct) value
res.models[0]['id']="fb8f83e2-e157-4e1e-8315-8e5f03b44691";

//Output what the id is, this is always the correct id!
console.log("res.models[0]['id']: ",res.models[0]['id']);
socket.emit("updateRealSeatSelect", res);
```

**Client side code:**

```
socket.on("updateRealSeatSelect", function(data){
    //Output the id when we get the object. This is always wrong!
    console.log("res.models[0]['id']: "+data.models[0]['id']);
});
```

The output is the problem. Here's what I get:

---

## Output

**Server Side Output:** (Correct)

```
res.models[0]['id']:  fb8f83e2-e157-4e1e-8315-8e5f03b44691
```

**Client Side Output:** (Wrong! Why is it different??)

```
res.models[0]['id']: b4fd12f1-61ca-4445-b916-62617f1c0a78
```

I have double triple quadruple checked that the **server is sending the correct object** with the correct id. **When the client gets the object, the object is different** and has the wrong id! How can this happen?

---

## Misc

**Attempts:**

- I tried copying `res` into a new object, then sending that, but that also didn't work. Like this:

  ```
  var newres = res;
  socket.emit("updateRealSeatSelect", newres);
  ```
- I also tried using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` when I send the object but this didn't help either. Like this:

  ```
  socket.emit("updateRealSeatSelect", JSON.stringify(res));
  ```

**Versions:**

- Express Version:  3.5.2
- Node Version: v6.5.0
- Socket.IO: v1.3.6

Comment: What happens if you do not assign the wrong value?

Comment: @PM77-1 Setting the wrong value first was to show that socket io is sending the old object. In my actual code the id is set somewhere else, then I replace that id and send the message. So I can't skip that step :( However when I output the object on the server side, it is correct. I don't know why it is correct on the server side and wrong on the client.

Comment: I was not suggesting anything.  I just wanted to know what happens without prior assignment.  Can you please check?

Comment: I can't skip that step. Skipping the initial generation step causes the application to skip all the steps.

Comment: Do you have a minimal version of your code that can be run and exhibit the problem?

Comment: Is the id set async anywhere in your original code?

Comment: I suspect that you have nested call-back functions and somewhere use a variable before its result is actually returned. That's why you do need [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think really happens, even though it is not demonstrated in your code example.

Your object's ID looks like UUID which may suggest Cassandra. Even if it's not Cassandra it's probably some database and thus that object is retrieved asynchronously, but you return the response before the object is actually retrieved and you also keep the object in a global variable or in an outer scope that is shared between the invocations of `socket.emit()`.

I also expect that the first `socket.emit()` after you restart your server returns no object at all and all subsequent responses get the previous one.

So this is not like this:

```
//The OLD (wrong) value
res.models[0]['id']="b4fd12f1-61ca-4445-b916-62617f1c0a78";

//The NEW (correct) value
res.models[0]['id']="fb8f83e2-e157-4e1e-8315-8e5f03b44691";

socket.emit("updateRealSeatSelect", res);
```

But more like this:

```
database.getObject(function (data, res) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        res = data;
    }
});
socket.emit("updateRealSeatSelect", res);
```

roughly speaking. Of course it's just speculation because you didn't provide an example that would let us reproduce the problem and you didn't explain the most relevant parts of your code either.

If you get the data asynchronously using callbacks or promises then make sure that you don't try to emit it to the socket before you actually have it.

Also, always use:

```
'use strict';
```

at the beginning of your code to make sure that you don't implicitly declare global variables.

And read about concurrency in JavaScript - callbacks, continuation passing style, promises, async functions.

You may have more luck using async function than traditional callbacks and promise handling, so instead of something like this using callbacks:

```
getFromDatabase(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        socket.emit('data', data);
    }
});
```

or something like this using promises:

```
getFromDatabase().then(function (data) {
    socket.emit('data', data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle error
});
```

you would write something like:

```
try {
    socket.emit('data', await getFromDatabase());
} catch (err) {
    // handle error
}
```

which may be more clear to follow the control flow.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips!! I think I can get it working now :)